# django choiceField with CheckboxSelectMultiple: all selected by default?

Tags: django-forms

I'm using a choiceField with the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget.
Is it possible to render all checkboxes as checked by default?
Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I am doing exactly that on a form using this

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
     photo_list = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
         label="Photos", 
         required=False, 
         help_text="Unselect the photos you want to delete", 
         choices=(), 
         widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked":""})
     )
```

Answer (score 18):

Just set the initial values from the field's choices, like this:

```
MY_CHOICES = (
    ("some", "Some choice"),
    ("another", "Another choice"),
    ("best", "Best choice")
)

...

multiple_choice = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    label=u"Select multiple", 
    choices=MY_CHOICES, 
    widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
    initial=(c[0] for c in MY_CHOICES)
)
```

Comment: This code was only working on first load for me. I had to change `initial` to an array for it to work correctly:
`initial = [c[0] for c in MY_CHOICES]`

Comment: @ben that's a list, not an array :)

Comment: Awsom !! It helped me. Thanks @Ben   This worked :     ```initial = [c[0] for c in MY_CHOICES]```