# Pre-selecting all the checkboxes when using django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django

I want to show pre-selected options to the user (since they are more likely to remove a few items rather than add all the items, which is a hassle).

Is it possible to pre-select all the checkboxes rendered by a ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Would this be done in the model, or the form?

I'd prefer not to use javascript to do it.

I can't find any documentation about pre-selecting for ModelMultipleChoiceField and official documentation is scant: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['my_items'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset=models.MyItem.objects.all(),
        initial=self.instance.MyItem.all())
```

If I add "checked" in the template, I get an error:

```
{% render_field form.my_items class+="form-control" checked %}
```

Error:

```
'render_field' tag requires a form field followed by a list of attributes and values in the form attr="value"
```

Comment: Try `initial=models.MyItem.all()` instead of `self.instance.MyItem.all()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229029/django-choicefield-with-checkboxselectmultiple-all-selected-by-default), you can just set `initial` to all values:

```
# Let's assume this is your choice set
CHOICES = (
    ('a', 'A'),
    ('b', 'B'),
    ('c', 'C')
)

field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    ...
    initial=[c[0] for c in CHOICES]
    ...
)
```

### Queryset

Let's assume you want to display Users. Just use:

```
...
queryset=User.objects.all(),
initial=[u for u in User.objects.all()])
...
```

It will look like (tried it myself):

[image]

Comment: How do you adapt that to a queryset? Also I just need "checked" to be outputted on the checkbox in HTML.